# CSS exclude a tag from * selector

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a small CSS style sheet. I want to restyle all the Text content to a Roboto font. 
I wrote this code below :    *{font-family:Roboto !important;}

Now How to select everything aside from the icon( I want to exclude the icons (i) tag from my selector, some do useFontAwesome some use other icon fonts)

So is there something that I can add to the * selector to select everything aside fro the icons?

Comment: just add back the icons with the right font in your css file

Comment: css has `:not()` selector

Comment: btw it's not a good idea to use `*`

Comment: Sure it works but here I want diffrent web apps/ pages to use this stylesheet and some have diffrent icon fonts so cannot do. Is there no way to exclude the Icons in the selector?

Comment: you should try to fix the way you change the font isntead of adding a *hack* to fix a *hack*

Comment: @Temani Afif in case where you have multiple websites and a client who want the changes on all the websites , you can create a single stylesheet across all your websites, which is something like a custom CDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a negation for the classes that you don't want to apply the style:

For example:

```
*:not(.fa) {
    font-family: Roboto !important;
}
```

Usually the icons are in "i" elements, you could do the following as well to affect any icons:

```
*:not(i) {
    font-family: Roboto !important;
}
```

But using "i" elements is not mandatory, and there could be icons that are not as "i" tags, as well as normal text as "i" tags (although this is very unusual)

Also, take into account that using "!important" is not a good practice, especially with a rule so generic.